# Rails 4 with kaminari. I need absolute urls in paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

kaminari seems to build url and ignored

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {
 :host => "localhost"
}
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
 :host => "localhost"
}
config.action_controller.asset_host ="localhost"
```

is there a way to force kaminari to append the hostname and maybe the port as well?

I found a way

```
module Kaminari
  module Helpers
    class Tag
      def page_url_for( page )
        # pp @template
        parameters = @params.merge( @param_name => (page <= 1 ? nil : page ) )
        parameters.merge!( ActionController::Base.default_url_options )
        @template.url_for parameters
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If there is a better way. let me know.

Comment: Why don't you answer your own question below so it's removed from the unanswered queue?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom thank you. i didn't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer

```
module Kaminari
  module Helpers
    class Tag
      def page_url_for( page )
        # pp @template
        parameters = @params.merge( @param_name => (page <= 1 ? nil : page ) )
        parameters.merge!( ActionController::Base.default_url_options )
        @template.url_for parameters
      end
    end
  end
end
```